# C++: Solve underdetermined linear system with lapack

Tags: c++, linear-algebra, lapack

Let's put it simple: I have an under-determined linear system of equations

> Ax = b

and I want to get one valid solution, no matter which one of the infinite solutions for the system. And I want to get it as efficiently as possible.

I have checked general LAPACK routines and it seems that they cannot handle the under-determined case. For example, `dgesv()`, whose documentation is found [here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d7/d3b/group__double_g_esolve_ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512.html#ga5ee879032a8365897c3ba91e3dc8d512), will return and integer larger than 1 in `INFO` if the factor U, from PLU factorization, is singular, and it will *not* solve the system if that is the case.

I have also checked some routines for Linear Least Squares problems (LLS) ([documentation here](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lug/node27.html)), which does exactly solve my problem, just not as efficiently as I wished. If the LLS problems I provide is under-determined, the LLS routine will return the vector that minimizes

> ||Ax-b||

Which is a valid solution. However, it is calculated as the solution to an optimization problem, and I was wondering if there is a more efficient way of obtaining a valid solution for my under-determined problem.

A similar question was made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7799065/c-library-for-undetermined-equation-systems), but I believe that my question is more concrete than that: I am using LAPACK, and I want to solve an under-determined system of linear equations as efficiently as possible.

Comment: What's the problem with reverse substitution? This question is more suited for scicomp.stackexchange.com

Comment: You can run `gelsd`, `gelsy` also from lapack but you need to extend your B matrix.

Answer (score 3):

*For an under-determined system of equations:*

The correct approach is to use singular value decomposition (**SVD**). **Lapack** offers singular value decomposition in the form of **dgesvd**.

To perform the **SVD** you will have to homogenize your problem to turn it into a matrix problem of the form: `My = 0`. This is easy to do by introducing another degree of freedom (another variable). This will transform the vector `x -> y` and matrix `A -> M`. When performing the **SVD** on the matrix `M`, the smallest singular vector will be the solution to your under-determined least squares problem.

I would recommend using **matlab** or **octave** to experiment before wasting time coding anything up.